# Prove that $f(m)$ is divisible by $3$ for all integers $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Given a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients whose value is divisible by $3$ for three integers $k,k+1,$ and $k+2,$ prove that $f(m)$ is divisible by $3$ for all integers $m$.

Since $f(k),f(k+1),f(k+2)$ are divisible by $3$ for some integer $k$, how may we use this to conclude that $f(m)$ is divisible by $3$?

Comment: Hint: look at $f(x+3)-f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For any polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients, we have $$a \equiv b \mod m \implies P(a) \equiv P(b) \mod m$$

If you don't know this property, try to prove it using induction to the degree of the polynomial $P$.

Comment: Can you show the proof, too?

Comment: @Puzzled417 That hint is basically the whole answer, you just need to apply it.

Comment: @KevinLong  I am trying to prove the result given in the hint.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Oh, sorry. Then, as wythagoras said, you just need induction, the fact that multiplication by integers preserves modular congruence (i.e. if $a,b,m,n$ are integers, then $a\equiv b \mod{m}\to na\equiv nb \mod{m})$ and that addition by integers preserved modular congruence (i.e. $a\equiv b \mod{m}\to a+n\equiv n+b\mod{m}$ for all integers $n$).

Comment: @Puzzled417 Alternatively, prove it for monomials, which reduces to showing that $a \equiv b \pmod m$ $\;\;\implies\;\;$ $a^k \equiv b^k \pmod m$, then use the fact that a polynomial is a sum of monomials.